# why is my JQuery Toggle password visibility is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, passwords, dom-traversal

```
<p class="input-group pwdField">
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" required>
   <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
</p>
```

This is my HTML markup and my jquery code is as below.

```
$(function() {

    $( ".input-group" ).children("i").click(function() {

        $( this ).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");

        var inputField = $(".pwdField").children().first();

        if ( $(inputField).attr("type", "password") ) {

            $(inputField).attr("type", "text");

        } else {
            $(inputField).attr("type", "password");
        }

    });

}); // End of document.ready();
```

Please help me, when I am clicking the eye icon in the input field, everythng is working perfectly but when I click again, the input field is not changing its attribute back to type="password" from typee="text"

Answer (score 3):

You are ***setting*** the attribute inside the `if()` not ***getting*** it so you can check it's value

Instead try doing something like:

```
// get the attribute value
var type = $(inputField).attr("type"); 
// now test it's value
if( type === 'password' ){
  $(inputField).attr("type", "text");
}else{
  $(inputField).attr("type", "password");
}
```

Note the difference ... you **set** when second argument is provided and **get** when it is not

Comment: Yeah. Got it after I posted the question. but thank you for your valuable answer.